# Where to find records of arrest in pre WW II Germany?

Tags: 20th-century, germany, jewish, criminal-records

A German Jew I am researching was arrested in Germany some time around 1935. He was released some time thereafter, and emigrated to the United states in 1936. I am wondering where to look for such arrest records. This event took place most likely in Kirchheimbolanden, in the Pfalz.

Comment: Gene, I think a bit more info is needed, like by whom this person was arrested: normal police, SS? Was he sent to a local prison, or some sort of pre war camp? May not be the nicest sort of questions to ask, but it may influence the choice of German archives to be searched for this.

Comment: I don't believe he was sent to a camp, I believe the arrest was local. I don't know which organization did the arresting: it could have been the local authorities or it could have been the Gestapo.

Comment: OK, I asked, because I know that lots of camp records are in the US, where they can be searched through Fold3. I'll put my ideas in the answer field.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't know much about the structure of the German Police in that era, nor about their possible cooperation with the Gestapo, I think the best place to start is the site of the BundesArchiv in Berlin.

You can find the English portal for the NS era here:

http://www.bundesarchiv.de/benutzung/zeitbezug/nationalsozialismus/index.html.en